# Make a DIV not be shown outside it's container

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, css

I'm making a very basic animation with JQuery. Basically what I have is a DIV in the size of 60% width, 80% height and it contains a manual. My goal is that when you go through pages in the manual, the current page moves up and disappears and the next page comes up from the bottom.

I'm close enough, but something's just wrong and I can't get an idea on how to fix it - 
**The page DIVs are visible outside their container. Their top property is set to 110% yet I can see it doesn't take effect. Their position is only affected by the menu table above them.**

So my problem, really is - **how do I make a DIV invisible outside it's container, but without changing the visibillity or display of the whole DIV, so the text will be seen when moving up - but only the text that lays on the container and isn't outside it.**

```
    .manualPage {
    color:rgba(241, 241, 241,1.0);
    top:110%;
    text-align:left;
    left:0%;
    cursor:default;
    z-index:30;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size:11pt;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.BigWindow {
    position:absolute;
    width:60%;
    height:80%;
    top:10%;
    display:inline-block;

    left:-70%;

    background-repeat:repeat;

    color:rgba(241, 241, 241,1.0);

    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size:12pt;

    text-align:center;

    cursor:default;

    z-index:30;
}
```

notice that BigWindow is the container, manualPage is a page.

Here's the function, but I think the CSS problem is the one to be solved first:

```
var currentPage = -1;

function setManualPage(num) {
    if ($('#manualMenu').css('display') != 'none')
        $('#manualMenu').fadeOut(750);
    if (currentPage != -1) {
        $('#page' + currentPage).animate({ top: '-100%' }, screen.availHeight / 2, function () { $('#page' + currentPage).css('top', '110%'); });
    }

    if (num != -1)
        $('#page' + num).animate({ top: '0%' }, screen.availHeight / 2);
    currentPage = num;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a jdfiddle or a code sample

Comment: @Lepidosteus code sample added

Answer (score 9):

basically this is done by adding CSS

```
overflow: hidden;
```

to the enclosing container, but without seeing the code over here, getting help is hard.

Comment: Now trying to add overflow hidden to the BigWindow CSS class.

Comment: Okay that was awful. It just worked. But it seems the only reason .manualPage's position is what it is, is because of the menu table. It's top is not really 110% like in the class I set.

Comment: Slightly fixed by setting the class'es position to absolute. Anyways, @Axel Amthor, thank you very much! Can't believe how one line solutions sometimes solve the frustration!

Answer (score 3):

try

```
 .manualPage{opacity:0}
```

OR

```
.manualPAge{visibility:hidden}
```

this way, all ages (`#page1`, `#page2` etc) with class manualPAge would not be visible.

during the animation, when you are setting the `top` property, set the `opacity` to `1` OR `visibility` to `visible`

another way to do it is to set the `overflow` property of the containing window:

```
          .BigWindow{overflow:hidden}
```

this way, any content exceeding the height of the `.BigWindow` would not be shown

Comment: you r welcome. when i started typing there was no answer to the question. next time i'll try to be fast :)